# Using cross-validation for model selection and model comparison

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, cart, caret

Let us suppose that we have two classifiers: SVM and CART. For each one of them, a set of hyperparameters is considered (C=0.001,0.01,... for SVM cp=... for CART).

The question is, can I use k-fold cross-val to perform model selection and model comparison using the same folds? That is, first select the hyperparameters that have the greatest average and then use the paired t-test to compare SVM and CART with the best hyperparameters calculated in the previous step. I reckon that this is what Caret does, but I do not know if it is correct.

Comment: I don't think any library would do both HPO and model comparison using the same folds unless you code them to do so. There is probably a nested CV involved.

Comment: I think that caret does this -> https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#between-models